# Can't I use different fragments at the same time using one button on the main?

Tags: android, android-fragments

First, here is my code. I have 3 Fragments, also have two buttons(`saveButton`, `deleteButton`) in `MainActivity`. If I press `Fragment A` and press the Save button, the dialogue will come out. Entering the name of `Fragment` on the Dialogue changes the title of `Fragment A`. The problem is that if I do this, did't change Fragment A,b,c title only C change. change title A, B -> change title C.... how can i separate one save button in each fragment? Is that possible??

```
   ((MainActivity)getActivity()).btn_save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            save_title = new EditText(getActivity());
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setTitle("서식 저장");
            builder.setMessage("서식명을 입력해주세요");
            builder.setView(save_title);

            builder.setPositiveButton("저장",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            if ((((MainActivity) getActivity()).value) == 1) {
                                String text = save_title.getText().toString();
                                sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("file", MODE_PRIVATE);
                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                                editor.putString("form1_title", text);
                                ((MainActivity) getActivity()).form_button1.setText(text);
                                editor.apply();
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "저장 완료", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });

            builder.setNegativeButton("취소", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                }
            });
            builder.show();
        }
    });
    ((MainActivity)getActivity()).btn_delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            fragment1 = new Frag1();
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

            builder.setMessage("삭제하시겠습니까?");
            builder.setPositiveButton("삭제",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @SuppressLint("CommitTransaction")
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            if ((((MainActivity) getActivity()).value) == 1) {
                                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, fragment1).commit();
                                sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("file", MODE_PRIVATE);
                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                                editor.remove("form1_title");
                                editor.apply();
                            }
                        }
                    });

            builder.setNegativeButton("취소", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            });
            builder.show();

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this by establishing communication between `Activity` & `Fragments`.

As a simplest approach, you can create public methods `fun saveData()` & `fun deleteData()` in all fragments and then you can call these methods from `MainActivity` by first getting the instance of current fragment as

```
val currentFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container)
```

and then invoking `currentFragment.saveData()` or `currentFragment.deleteData()` on respective button clicks.